# Http post call slow processing issues

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8

I am facing some processing speed issues with my wp8 app.

I have some questions and answers in my post call. I tried with whole question and just ID but it is processed in same time.

```
if (ansNo.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || ansYes.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
{
    if (ansNo.IsChecked == true || ansYes.IsChecked == true)
    {
        string token = Globals.token;
        int counter = Globals.counter;
        Globals.counter = Globals.counter + 1;
        quizStatus.Text = "";
        if (ansNo.IsChecked == true)
        {
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(quesId.Text, "f"));
        }
        else
        {
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(quesId.Text, "t"));
        }
        getQuiz(token, Globals.counter);
        ansYes.IsChecked = false;
        ansNo.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        quizStatus.Text = "Please Select An Answer";
    }
}
else
{
    calculateType(values);
}
```

`getquiz` gets the next question and `quesId` holds the id for question and `calculatetype` is the function where I am facing issues.

Here is `calculatetype`:

```
public async Task calculateType(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values) 
{
    //quizText.Text = values.ToString();
    quizText.Text = "Calculating Type...";
    nextButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://107.170.34.31:3000/calculateusertype", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var typeResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JToken r = JToken.Parse(typeResponse);


    userResult.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ansYes.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ansNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ContentPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    userType.Text = r["type"].ToString();
}
```

here is my getquestion function

```
public async Task getQuiz(String token,int counter)
    {
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            JToken p = JToken.Parse(Globals.responseString);
            int arryCount = p["questions"].Count() - 1;
            if (counter <= arryCount)
            {
                //quizText.Text = p["questions"][counter]["_id"].ToString();
                quizText.Text = p["questions"][counter]["question"].ToString();
                quesId.Text = p["questions"][counter]["_id"].ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                quizText.Text = "You Have Completed The Test. Click Next to Get Your Type.";
                ansYes.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ansNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", token)
                };

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://107.170.34.31:3000/quiz", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Globals.responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JToken o = JToken.Parse(Globals.responseString);
            Globals.quizcount = o["questions"].Count();
            Globals.answers = new string[Globals.quizcount];
            //o = JObject.Parse(responseString);
            if (Globals.responseString != "")
            {

                //quizText.Text = o["questions"][counter]["_id"].ToString();
                quizText.Text = o["questions"][counter]["question"].ToString();
                quesId.Text = o["questions"][counter]["_id"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions to make this faster?

Comment: Are you running this on the UI thread? Are you getting all the questions/answers in one go, or loading them remotely on demand?

Comment: yes i am runing that on ui thread. and loading questions/answer on demand. when user answer the answer is saved in a key value pair after the complete quiz i just pass the values to post call

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start off by doing some profiling, to make sure you fix the right problems.

That said, it's most likely a result of hitting the web service on demand. Your web service APIs should be "chunky, not chatty". In other words, try loading all the questions (and answers) when the user starts the quiz.

Comment: i have update my question. i am doing same as u r saying. for first question i just make a call and afterward i just parse the response string from that call. I am getting issue after the  quiz in submitting the answers.